# Objective-C Simplest way to create comma separated string from an array of objects

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

So I have a nsmutablearray with a bunch of objects in it.  I want to create a comma separated string of the id value of each object.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Use the `NSArray` instance method `componentsJoinedByString:`.

In Objective-C:

```
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

In Swift:

```
func componentsJoinedByString(separator: String) -> String
```

**Example:**

In Objective-C:

```
NSString *joinedComponents = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

In Swift:

```
let joinedComponents = array.joined(seperator: ",")
```

Comment: So the objects in my array have 4 or 5 properties, how do I tell it to join just the id values?

Comment: If you just log one of your objects what do you get?  Just the id values?  If so, that's what you'll get with componentsJoinedBuString: Try it and see.

Comment: @Jhorra If you want an array of just one of the properties, you can do something really awesome: `[<NSArray instance> valueForKey:@"<string representation of property name>"]` and it'll return an array of just that property. Then call `componentsJoinedByString:` on the result. Behind the scenes, the framework is iterating through all of the objects in the array and calling `valueForKey:` on them. Key-Value Coding is awesome!

Comment: For more KVC Collection Operators, check this out: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Answer (score 7):

If you're searching for the same solution in Swift, you can use this:

```
var array:Array<String> = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
var commaSeperatedString = ", ".join(array) // Results in string1, string2, string3
```

To make sure your array doesn't contains nil values, you can use a filter:

```
array = array.filter { (stringValue) -> Bool in
    return stringValue != nil && stringValue != ""
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for NSMutableArray in Swift. Searching Google has yet to reveal an answer.

Comment: @Twan Thank you, your answer is (almost) exactly what I was looking for... Almost, because I need to concatenate optional Strings, some of which could be nil (and so I don't want to concatenate them), but this solution doesn't accept optionals String, it requires to unwrap them... maybe you had a similar issue in the past, if so could you help me?

Comment: @cdf1982 I've updated my answer. You can do this using the filter method.

Comment: @Twan it's perfect, thank you really, really, really very much! I'm just sorry that this is a comment and I can't accept it!

Answer (score 5):

**Create String from Array:**

```
-(NSString *)convertToCommaSeparatedFromArray:(NSArray*)array{
    return [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
```

**Create Array from String:**

```
-(NSArray *)convertToArrayFromCommaSeparated:(NSString*)string{
    return [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

```
var commaSeparatedString = arrayOfEntities.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

Comment: The question specified a programming language. Please consider changing it to objective - c.

Comment: @handiansom That was 2012.

Comment: Yeah I noticed too. ^ ^